# How to pull previous day's records for weekdays only?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this simple query that returns previous day's data.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(datetime,mytable.mydate, 121),GETDATE()) = 1
```

Using this query becomes an issue on Mondays since the previous day is Sunday but there is no data on Sunday.

So I would like the query to retrieve Friday's data (last activity) on Monday

Any ideas how to do this?

Just a little note about date data type. The date field is of `VARCHAR` data type.

I inherited the database and has been in use now for over 10 years.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Is `mydate` really a `varchar()`?  You should be storing dates as date/time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes it is a varchar unfortunately. As indicated in my original post, I inherited this. I would never store dates as string or varchar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES t.*
FROM mytable t
WHERE mydate < CAST(getdate()  as DATE) -- assume mydate is a date
ORDER BY CAST(mydate as DATE) DESC;
```

This will get the most recent day's data in the table, for any day where there is data.

EDIT:

Apparently, `mydate` is stored in a varchar.  This is a bad idea, but if you are going to do it, then format 121 is a very good choice.  I would modify the above as:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES t.*
FROM mytable t
WHERE mydate < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 121)
ORDER BY LEFT(mydate, 10) DESC;
```

Note:  this does the comparison of the dates as strings.  But that is okay, because the dates are in the format YYYY-MM-DD, which is comparable.  If performance is an issue, I would advise a computed column on `mydate` (to convert to a datetime or date) with an index on the column.

Comment: a `cast` for `mydate` in the `where` clause as it is a `varchar`?

Comment: @vkp - Since RHS is `Date`, LHS will be internally converted to `DATE`. `DATE` has higher precedence than `varchar`

Comment: Thanks @Prdp .. didn't know that.

Comment: @Gordon, et al who responded very quickly, thank you very much.

The first query works although I would not be able to affirm this until I run it next Monday. 

However, the second query seems to think that previous day's record is 2/9/2016 which is incorrect. By the way, that's the format on our table.

Comment: @Tairoc you can test it today using `where mydate < '20170123'` instead of `getdate()`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. It asumes sunday at the first day of the week.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(datetime,mytable.mydate, 121),GETDATE()) = case datepart(dw, GETDATE())
when 2 then 3 --read 3 days back on a monday
when 1 then 2 --read 2 days back on a sunday
else 1 end
```

Comment: thank you.

I don't understand the Saturday bit though. Could you shed some light?

No data is usually available on Saturdays and Sundays, only Mondays through Fridays.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a `datetime` variable, and, with `DATEPART()`, determine which day of the week `GETDATE()` is (which day the query is being run).  Then, on Mondays, change our date by negative two days.

```
declare @queryDate datetime;
set @queryDate = case when DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 1 then DATEADD(d, -2, GETDATE()) else GETDATE() end;
select * from mytable 
where DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(datetime,mytable.mydate, 121),@queryDate) = 1
```